# Error 400 Bad Request when using Twitter API with requests

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I´m playing around with the Twitter API and I try to use `requests` to send a tweet via Twitter (I want to port it on an embedded system).

At first, I checked the `create_tweet.py` example from Twitter and use some code to generate the OAuth keys:

```
import os

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

consumer_key = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_KEY")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_SECRET")

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret = consumer_secret)

    try:
        fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write")
    except ValueError:
        print(
            "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
        )

    resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
    resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
    print("Got OAuth token: %s" % resource_owner_key)

    base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
    authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
    print("Please go here and authorize: %s" % authorization_url)

    access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    oauth = OAuth1Session(
        consumer_key,
        client_secret = consumer_secret,
        resource_owner_key = resource_owner_key,
        resource_owner_secret = resource_owner_secret,
        verifier = input("Paste the PIN here: "),
    )
    oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)

    print("oauth_token: {}".format(oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]))
    print("oauth_token_secret: {}".format(oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]))
```

I have copied the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` and added them to my second program to transmit the tweet:

```
import os
import json
import time
import string
import random
import requests

consumer_key = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_KEY")

payload = {"text": "Hello world1!"}

oauth_token = <oauth_token from program above>
oauth_token_secret = <oauth_token_secret from program above>

headers = {
    "OAuth oauth_consumer_key": consumer_key,
    "oauth_nonce": "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(32)),
    "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1",
    "oauth_timestamp": str(int(time.time())),
    "oauth_token": oauth_token_secret,
    "oauth_version": "1.0",
    "oauth_signature": oauth_token,
}

response = requests.post("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets", headers = headers, json = payload)

if(response.status_code != 201):
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
    )

print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

json_response = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent = 4, sort_keys = True))
```

But I got a `400 Bad Request` error.

What is the reason for the bad request error? How do I have to improve the request?